# C++ Trying to set pointers to new objects

Tags: c++, pointers, object

My program has a total of 10 objects which are set equal to an object pointer when created, here are the object pointers; a1,b1,b2,c1,c2,c3,d1,d2,d3, and d4. I have set each pointer to 0 initially. And I test for this in order for the program to know which objects of type A, B, C, or D have already been created. My problem is that the program does not do what I want, for type B objects, the first should be pointed to by b1 and then the next B object should be pointed to by b2, and likewise for C and D. But what happens is that b1 changes what it points to instead of the program recognizing that b1 is set and moving to b2.

Here is a portion of the class member function:

```
void Board::addShip(char type, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    //Add a ship to the board. If the board already contains ten ships, the new ship should be ignored.
    Ship *a1=0,*b1=0,*b2=0,*c1=0,*c2=0,*c3=0,*d1=0,*d2=0,*d3=0,*d4=0;
    if (type == 'A' && a1==0)
    {
        cout << "a1" << endl;
        a1 = new AircraftCarrier(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        shipList.push_back(a1);
    }
    else if (type == 'B')
    {
        if (b1 == 0)
        {
            cout << "b1" << endl;
            b1 = new BattleShip(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            shipList.push_back(b1);
        }
        else if (b2 == 0)
        {
            cout << "b2" << endl;
            b2 = new BattleShip(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            shipList.push_back(b2);
        }
    }
```

The cout statements are there for testing purposes.

Comment: `b1` is a local variable. You just set it to 0 right there and there's nothing changing it before it's compared with 0.

Comment: I condensed a bit sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is all of `a1, b1...` are *local variables* with *automatic storage* in the method `addShip`. So each time you call that method, these variables are created and initialzied to `zero`. That's why each time the first one is created (since for ex. `a1==0` is true each time).

Several solutions exists:

1. You can make the variables `static`, so that they will be created only first time and will retain their values.
2. Better solution would be to make them *class member* in class `Board`, because they represents components of `Board` (I guess). Then you will initialize them to `zero`(better `NULL/nullptr`) in the constructor of `Board` class.

Comment: ok that makes sense, i add the pointers to a vector, if I reference the vector instead of the local pointers that should work right?

Comment: @RakibulHasan What ruakh means is that both `static` and regular variables are local variables. The storage type of `static` variables are static while those of regular variables are automatic.

Comment: @RakibulHasan To make your answer better you should use 'local variables with automatic storage' instead of just 'local variables'.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was confusing; R Sahu's interpretation was what I meant. Your edit addresses my comment, which I'll now delete. +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you already know the source of your problem and how to fix it. I am going to suggest something to make your code a bit simpler.

```
void Board::addShip(char type, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
   //Add a ship to the board. If the board already contains ten ships, the new ship should be ignored.
   static int acount = 0;
   static int bcount = 0;
   static int ccount = 0;
   static int dcount = 0;

   if (type == 'A' && acount < 1)
   {
      ++acount;
      shipList.push_back(new AircraftCarrier(x1,y1,x2,y2));
   }
   else if (type == 'B' && acount < 2 )
   {
      ++bcount;
      shipList.push_back(new BattleShip(x1,y1,x2,y2));
   }
   else if (type == 'C' && acount < 3 )
   {
      ++ccount;
      shipList.push_back(/* new C Ship */ );
   }
   else if (type == 'D' && dcount < 4 )
   {
      ++dcount;
      shipList.push_back(/* new D Ship */ );
   }
}
```